# merge two queries into one for partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two oracle queries. And I want to merge these queries into one. First query always gives one record as a result.

1).

```
select distinct partition_name 
from all_tab_partitions 
where partition_name like 'P_20130110%';
```

2).

```
select feed_id,count(*) 
from str_bill_item partition(result of first query) 
group by feed_id 
order by 1;
```

Actually str_bill_item table having some partition in which data is stored. and name of that partition are stored in all_tab_partition table. so I need to take the particular partition name from all_tab_partition then found the data in that partition form str_billl_item table.

Please help me on that?

Thanks.

Comment: When posting SQL questions, you should almost always include which RDBMS you're using as one of your tags.

Comment: could you more information how the output should look? because actually it does not make any sense

Comment: Output of first query is always in form of "P_20120110", only one record will be come

Comment: you probably need to join first query with second..

Comment: Yes...Justin. But how can we do this?

Comment: @sumit vrdi I'm guessing that `partition_name` from first query is linked with table `str_bill_item`, but I don't know with what column... give `str_bill_item` table column list with sample data

Comment: what i mean is, what result do you want form merging this query? and what would be good is when u can describe more what you are trying to  accomplish

Comment: Justin parition_name is not a column in str_bill_item, partition_name is like a partition of the str_bill_item table inwhich data is stored

Comment: COLUMN OF STR_BILL_ITEM
BILL_ITEM_ID
CSA_BILL_ID
ITEM_VGE_ID
NUMBER_OF_CALLS
SOURCE_COUNTRY_ID
TARGET_COUNTRY_ID
SOURCE_NETWORK_ID
TARGET_NETWORK_ID
DURATION
CHARGE
CHARGE_OPCO_C
USAGE_DATE
FEED_ID
CALLING_NUMBER
CALLED_NUMBER
VOLUME
SUSCRIBER_ID
CHARGEABLE
PCTG_CHARGED
PRODUCT
CREATION_DATE
TARIFF_TYPE
USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS
HOST_ID
CONFERENCE_ID
CONTRACT_ID
SUBSCRIBER_FIRST_NAME
SUBSCRIBER_LAST_NAME
SUBSCRIBER_COST_CENTRE

Comment: could you edit your question pls

Comment: Domi..Actually str_bill_item table having some partition inwhich data is stored. and name of that partition are stored in all_tab_partition table. so I need to take the particular partition name from all_tab_partition then found the data in that partition form str_billl_item table.

Comment: when you run `select * from all_tab_partitions where table_name =  'STR_BILL_ITEM'` you will get some rows right?

Comment: Yes..Domi..this query will get only one row and i am not using "selct *" I am using "select distinct partition_name from all_tab_partitions 
where partition_name like 'P_20130110%';"
Suppose output of first query is "P_20130110" then second query should be "select feed_id,count(*) from str_bill_item partition(P_20130110) group by feed_id  order by 1;"

Comment: if my answer is help for accept it, do it also with your other questions

Comment: Why are you not applying a predicate to the query that would allow partition pruning to identify the correct partition on your behalf? I have never seen anyone follow a coding pattern like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah i see the problem is you can't use a query in partition()

how about something like this:

```
DECLARE
  rPartName VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN

  select distinct partition_name 
  INTO rPartName
  from all_tab_partitions 
  where partition_name like 'P_20130110%';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select feed_id,count(*)  from str_bill_item partition('|| rPartName ||') group by feed_id order by 1;';

end;
```

what u could try to is:

run the select without execute and use

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('select feed_id,count(*)  from str_bill_item partition('|| rPartName ||') group by feed_id order by 1;');
```

run the  output as select if u get the same error it is somewhere in the sql query

if not execute has a problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can we store the result of first query in a variables?

Comment: Hi Domi..Thanks for query but this query gives some error in oracle
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"

Comment: Actually, when i remove the "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select feed_id,count(*)  from str_bill_item partition(9&rPartName) group by feed_id order by 1;';" then query is execute without error, so problem is coming in second query

Comment: Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.

Comment: first try to remove the `;` at the end